# Using requireJS to load 'lib/request' inside html code

Tags: javascript, html, neo4j, requirejs, requestjs

I'm trying to create a webpage that will make requests into a neo4j database.

I do the request from a javascript file `/projectFolder/js/query.js`:

```
function submitQuery() {
  var r = require("request");
  var txUrl = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit";

  //defines the cypher query
  var query="MATCH (n:Word) RETURN n, labels(n) as l LIMIT {limit}"
  var params={limit: 10}
  var cb=function(err,data) { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) }

  r.post({uri:txUrl,
          json:{statements:[{statement:query,parameters:params}]}},
          function(err,res) { cb(err,res.body)})

}
```

and in my `projectFolder/index.html` I have:

```
.
.
.
<script data-main="js/query.js" src="js/libs/require-2.1.20.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="query.js"></script>
</head>
.
.
.
```

When I call the `submitQuery()` function it doesn't go through the `var r = require("request");` line.

I've searched for some related issues and ended up trying inserting

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: './js/',
    paths: {
        request:'libs/require',
        },
});
```

at the beginning of my `query.js`, but got the same output.

Can someone give me a light? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a node.js module ("request") from a browser. Browsers do not natively support node.js, and do not have a `require` function.

If you really need to use node.js modules, you should look into using [browserify](http://browserify.org/index.html) to bundle up your node.js client code into a script that *can* run in a browser.

Otherwise, [this example that uses jQuery](https://blassklaus.wordpress.com/2015/02/06/calling-neo4j-from-javascript/) may be helpful.